# MVC5 EF6.1 Code First Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, entity-framework-6

```
public class Names
{
    [Key]
    public int NameID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class People
{
    [Key]
    public int PeopleID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int FirstNameID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FirstNameID")]
    public Names FirstName { get; set; }
    public int MiddleNameID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MiddleNameID")]
    public Names MiddleName { get; set; }
    public int LastNameID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LastNameID")]
    public Names LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

After creating the migration and trying to update the database, I'm getting the following error:

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.People_dbo.Names_LastNameID' on table 'People' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I added the following to the context, based on other articles I've seen online, but it did not do what I wanted it to.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }
```

Here's the resulting Migration Code...

```
namespace MyDataSet.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class PeopleNameIDs : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Names",
                c => new
                    {
                        NameID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.NameID)
                .Index(t => t.Name, unique: true);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.People",
                c => new
                    {
                        PeopleID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        FirstNameID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        MiddleNameID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        LastNameID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        DateOfBirth = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.PeopleID)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Names", t => t.FirstNameID, cascadeDelete: true)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Names", t => t.LastNameID, cascadeDelete: true)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Names", t => t.MiddleNameID, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.FirstNameID)
                .Index(t => t.MiddleNameID)
                .Index(t => t.LastNameID);

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.People", "MiddleNameID", "dbo.Names");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.People", "LastNameID", "dbo.Names");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.People", "FirstNameID", "dbo.Names");
            DropIndex("dbo.People", new[] { "LastNameID" });
            DropIndex("dbo.People", new[] { "MiddleNameID" });
            DropIndex("dbo.People", new[] { "FirstNameID" });
            DropIndex("dbo.Names", new[] { "Name" });
            DropTable("dbo.People");
            DropTable("dbo.Names");
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to have a "People" table where all of the *NameIDs are foreign keys to the Names table. However, only FirstName is required. When I first tested this out, and I only had the foreign key on FirstNameID, it worked fine. But when I copy/pasted the same to the other names, well that's where I'm at now.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cascade delete can be turned off only with fluent configuration. However, what you have tried

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

has no effect, because you have no `many-to-many` relationship, but 3 `one-to-many` relationships. Instead, you should configure each relationship separately:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<People>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.FirstName)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.FirstNameID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<People>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.MiddleName)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.MiddleNameID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<People>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.LastName)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.LastNameID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: I should try something before I dismiss it. All those that had "HasRequired" I assumed needed a [Required] for the ID, and since two of them weren't, I didn't figure it would work. Thank you very much for your assistance.